# What is happening to this tree?

Tags: species-identification, botany, mycology

I was walking down to my mailbox when I saw this tree:

[image]

And by the looks of the branches, the tree seems to be dying because it has no leaves.  What is happening to the tree?

Comment: Look like ther's both crust and brackets. Fairly underdeveloped thus far. Could be just as you said - the tree is dying - or, is suffering from a disease. I'm definitely no arborist, but I don't think I'm too far off either.. Where do you live? Also, would it be possible to provide a picture of the entire tree? Thanks.

Comment: They may be lichens or some other fungi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tree is dying.  From what you say, it has no leaves wduring a time it should, it has saprophitic growth along the trunk; it looks like there's a crack in the bark on the right, and there are [shoots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_shoot) coming up from the base of the trunk, the last hurrah from the tree to try to regenerate.

Trees send up suckers as a reaction to stress (like slowly dying). If you cut the trunk in such a way as to discourage rot, it will likely be replaced by this shrubby growth if the roots are sound. Some loggers use this as a way to quick-start new lumber trees.